# Prometheus metrics wont show for Java class

Tags: prometheus, javaagents

Okay, this problem is driving me up a wall, I can't figure out why Prometheus won't serve metrics. I got to 192.168.2.13:8534/metrics but all I get is the spinner contacting the port. I go to "wget http://localhost:8055" locally inside the container and I get

"Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8055... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response..."

Docker is pointing 8543 -> 8055

I call my app to start which is nothing more than a class with Main method. With the call below my class app starts and responds perfectly. I also open JVisualVM and JMX show all the JVM info and metrics perfectly. I can attach a debugger no problem.

```
java -javaagent:"/pro/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.13.0.jar=8055:/pro/prometheus/config_prometheus.yaml" -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/heapdump.hprof -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=31787 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=31787 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.2.13 -cp $LIBS service.core2.BootStrap
```

How can it be that Prometheus won't server metrics but JMX works fine? my config file is really simple.

```
startDelaySeconds: 0
ssl: false
lowercaseOutputName: false
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
port: 8055
```

I have tried everything I can think of.

- changed JVMs 8/9
- changed operating systems. diff docker images Ubuntu 16/18/20
- verified paths
- permissions
- tried different ports and verified they are reachable.
- tried differnet "jmx_prometheus_javaagent-" jars

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you open the targets on the prometheus dashboard is it down? And at the same time when you hit the metrics end point on the browser you can see the metrics? If you are using prometheus+docker and your java app is not on the same network (I mean, not running on docker), they cannot see each other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in the underlying code was calling an embedded Jetty server thus the actual pace where I needed the metrics from. Now to figure out how to get metrics from embedded jetty.